# how to update pages without using settimeout?Settimeout is slowing down the page in chrome.Is There any api for that

Tags: php, jquery, real-time

I  Tried  Settimeout to  update  pages,it  works  Perfect  in  Mozilla,
But  it is Slowing  down page in  Google Chrome.

Comment: Always try to show us some codes

Comment: Actally i was eager to  know is  there any alternative to  settimeout ajax call,I heard about Long Polling Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed alternatives to AJAX. And some of them rather amazing, to be honest.

I work for a company called Realtime (http://www.realtime.co) and we developed a very cool framework to work with real-time data.

It works on the cloud, we offer a lot of different APIs, you don't need to install anything and you can get a free account (with 1.000.000 free messages and 30.000 users per month). It allows you to push data to browsers, meaning you won't be hammering your server with AJAX requests.

On browsers, it uses websockets, if available. For older, non-websocket browsers, we will transparently fallback to whatever is that your browser can use.

Check out http://www.realtime.co and http://www.xrtml.org for downloads and documentation. Please let me know if you need any help as I am the Developer Evangelist for Realtime.

Comment: Hey  How  to i  Get Started?

Comment: Register at https://app.realtime.co/developers/getlicense as a developer and you'll get a free license. Then head out to http://docs.xrtml.org/. Start by taking a look at the Getting Started and Basic Concepts sections and move up towards the interactive tutorials. It's all there! If you need any help, contact me and I'll get you up to speed: scosta at realtime dot co (not com).